# binomial option pricing model - problem with risk-neutral probability

Tags: options, option-pricing, binomial

I have a little problem: 
in the binomial option pricing model, the price of a european derivative security $V_{n}$ satisfies:
$V_{n}=[1/(1+r)]*[\tilde{p}*optionUp +\tilde{q}*optionDown]$
where:
$\tilde{p}=\frac{e^{r*\Delta T} -d}{u-d}$
But when I read the article "option pricing model" on Wikipedia(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_options_pricing_model), the $\tilde{p}$ of Wikipedia's $\textbf{algorithm}$ is slightly different: 
$\tilde{p}=\frac{(ue^{-r*\Delta T} -1)*u}{u^2-1}$ (I take q=0)
I try to compare these 2 forms but they are not equal... why ???
Thanks !
:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the link you provided, by noting the construction of array p[], p0 and p1 are respectively the discounted $\texttt{down}$ and $\texttt{up}$ probabilities. Since $d=\frac{1}{u}$, then
\begin{align*}
p0 &= e^{-r \Delta T}\, \frac{u-e^{(r-q)\Delta T}}{u-d}\\
&= \frac{\big(u\,e^{-r \Delta T} -e^{-q\Delta T}\big)u }{u^2-1},
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
p1 &= e^{-r \Delta T}\,\big(1-p0\, e^{r \Delta T}\big)\\
&=e^{-r \Delta T} - p0.
\end{align*}
Note that $p1\, e^{r \Delta T}$ and $p0\, e^{r \Delta T}$ are respectively the $\texttt{up}$ and $\texttt{down}$ probabilities.

Comment: God bless you !  I'm a bit embarred actually it was very simple one(but I'm a beginner)... Thank you !